# Can't add Apache to start at boot with chkconfig (opensuse 13.1)

Tags: apache, lamp, opensuse

I'm running **opensuse 13.1**, and I installed **Apache2** as part of LAMP.

**Apache2** works just fine, except I can't make it **start automatically with boot**.

I used "chkconfig -a apache2" command (as described [here](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Apache_installation)) 
which gives an error `"apache2: unknown service"`.

Appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache2 has been migrated to systemd. `chkconfig` works only for SysV services.

The following command (apparently) worked for me:

```
systemctl enable apache2.service
```

It seems that the OpenSUSE doc is out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Find the name of the service:

```
ls -al /etc/init.d/
```

(Look for apache or httpd)

Then use that name in chkconfig.

Comment: can't find apache or httpd

Comment: just so you know, I used the [rcapache2 start] command to start apache